# PHP replace last x character in console

Tags: php, linux, bash

I want to replace last x character from console output. 
I can remove complete line by using `\r`.
 But is there a way to just remove last x character from console output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **PHP**:

To print a backspace character, use `0x08`.  BUT, there's a problem.  If you follow that by a newline `"\n"` (which you normally would) then the cursor is moved back to EOL, and the characters are exposed again.  Good news is that if you follow the `0x08` with the same number of spaces, it works fine.  For example, to remove the last two characters:

```
<?php
    print "Hello";
    printf("%c%c",0x08,0x08);
    print "  \n";
?>
```

Which prints `Hel`.  Note the use of `printf()` with `%c` to use an integer (0x08) as a character.

For a generic way to remove x number of characters:

```
<?php
    $x = 4;
    $str = "Those who are about to die salute you";
    $hacky = str_repeat(chr(0x08),$x).str_repeat(" ",$x);
    print "$str$hacky\n";
?>
```

which prints `Those who are about to die salute`.  Note the use of `chr(0x08)` here, which returns the character at position 8 in the character set.

Comment: I want to remove x character after printing output. Something like \b put php don't support \b

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `cut` command.

Comment: cut command I need to run before printing the output. I want to remove x character after printing output.